# Replacing a group while replacing a string

Tags: php, regex

```
$val = '<span>Hello World</span>';
echo preg_replace('/<(.+?)>(.+?)<\/(.+?)>/', "$1 $2 $3", $val);
```

This returns:

> span Hello World span

Is it possible to replace the second group? The second group is `Hello World` but it could be anything, since it is a dynamic value. What I want is to replace all white spaces with `_`.

I would like to do it without any further PHP functions. So it should be RegEx only.

Comment: see if this works `<(.+?)>(.+?)\s(.+?)<\/(.+?)>` [See Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gtr2Ut/1)

Comment: @Matt.G no, the output of `preg_replace('/<(.+?)>(.+?)\s(.+?)<\/(.+?)>/', "$1 $2 $3 $4", $val);` is: span Hello World span

Comment: `_` is missing between $2 and $3. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gtr2Ut/1)

Comment: @Matt.G thank you, this works great with the string "Hello World". But what if the string is very long and I want to replace all white spaces with `_`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a good candidate for `preg_replace_callback`.

```
$value = '<span>Hello World</span>';

echo preg_replace_callback('/<(.+?)>(.+?)<\/(.+?)>/', function (array $matches) {
    $matches[2] = str_replace(' ', '_', $matches[2]);
    return "{$matches[1]} {$matches[2]} {$matches[3]}";
}, $value);
```